# The property 'Roles' on type 'User_XXX' cannot be set because the collection is already set to an EntityCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I am getting this error The property 'Roles' on type 'User_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX15F53FF9BEC00DDCC7A54AD9857A0E30CFF2F17D7883FBCF8' cannot be set because the collection is already set to an EntityCollection.
I think the error is coming from here

```
 var thisuser = db.Users.Include(u => u.Roles).ToList().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Id); !Error Here I think
                thisuser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                thisuser.LastName = user.LastName;
                thisuser.UserName = user.UserName;
                thisuser.Password = user.Password;
```

Comment: can you post more code about your models?

Comment: @NachoLaborde how do you mean? Are you talking about more on from this controller?

Comment: about your entities, user and role